# Weird gcc compile behavior macOS Sierra: .dSYM subdirectory creation

Tags: gcc, atom-editor, macos-sierra

Why while compiling in Atom using `gcc` I get this strange folder?

```
- programname.dSYM
    - Contents
        - Resources
            - DWARF
                programname
```

See this [demo video](https://youtu.be/k5rEOTWy9GM) for further details (YouTube).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html), I think you are looking at separated debugging information.  The information in these files allows you to analyze crash dumps, without distributing the debugging information in the files you ship to your users (where it might reveal secrets you do not want to share).

Comment: The document you linked is very interesting. I supposed that this "problem" was caused by runnning an Atom package while compiling with bad linked libraries, so removing that useless pkg and linking the correct libraries and this 'solved' fir me.